# Neo4j to MS SQL ETL

Tags: sql-server-2019, etl, neo4j

There is Neo4j graph database storing devices data, I need those data need to out in MS SQL Reporting Data warehouse database. So essentially, I need conversion from Graph Database into RDMBS strong type and schema based tables. I wanted to understand what the various way we can do this ETL and what among best it can give best performance As the data syncing need to be near to real time (max 30 min. older data can be fine).

Please advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So this isn't a one time migration, the Neo4j database will continue to be used and you need to periodically synchronize the data to the SQL Server database?

Comment: That is correct @J.D.